# Enable webpage for IE Search Provider

Tags: internet-explorer, search-engine

When we visit Stack Overflow, the IE Instant Search Dropdown button is turning orange indicating that SO can be added as a search provider.

What code should I put inside my web page for IE to detect that it's a compatible search web page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to create an **OpenSearch description document**, and then include a link to it in your HTML header.

The [OpenSearch doco](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1#OpenSearch_description_document) page shows this example of a **description document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
   <ShortName>Web Search</ShortName>
   <Description>Use Example.com to search the Web.</Description>
   <Tags>example web</Tags>
   <Contact>admin@example.com</Contact>
   <Url type="application/rss+xml" 
    template="http://example.com/?q={searchTerms}&amp;pw={startPage?}&amp;format=rss"/>
 </OpenSearchDescription>
```

Then in your HTML header, include something like:

```
<link rel="search"
       type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
       href="http://example.com/content-search.xml"
       title="Content search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Example taken right from the SO source:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="http://sstatic.net/so/opensearch.xml">
```

Read more here: http://www.opensearch.org/